QueryDosDeviceW always returns 0 when it called in thread
QueryDosDeviceW returns 0 when called from a source other than the main thread. Why?
I used Visual Studio 2022 (v143) platform.
Below is the test code and output.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <windows.h>

std::vector<std::string> GetAvailableSerialPortsNames() {
  std::vector<std::string> com_names;
  TCHAR lp_target_path[5000];
  for (int i = 0; i <= 255; i++) { // checking ports from COM0 to COM255
    std::string com_name = "COM" + std::to_string(i); // converting to COM0, COM1, COM2
    DWORD Test 
      = QueryDosDeviceW((LPCWSTR)(
        std::wstring(com_name.begin(), com_name.end()).c_str()), 
        (LPWSTR)lp_target_path, 5000);
    if (Test != 0)
      com_names.push_back(com_name);
    if (::GetLastError() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) {
      lp_target_path[10000]; // in case the buffer got filled, increase size of the buffer.
      continue;
    }
  }
  return com_names;
}

int main(void) {
  auto serials = GetAvailableSerialPortsNames();
  std::cout << "Querying in main thread. Ports count=" << serials.size() << std::endl;
  for (auto s : serials) std::cout << s << std::endl;

  std::thread([]() {
    auto serials = GetAvailableSerialPortsNames();
    std::cout << "Querying in other thread. Ports count=" << serials.size() << std::endl;
    for (auto s : serials) std::cout << s << std::endl;
  }).detach();
  
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));

  return 0;
}

Querying in main thread. Ports count=3
COM1
COM3
COM4
Querying in other thread. Ports count=0

------EDIT
I was originally using Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 10, and there were no problems here. However, this problem occurred when built in Windows 11 Visual Studio 2022. The changed environment is as follows.
Platform: Visual Studio 2019 (v142) -> Visual Studio 2022 (v143)
Windows SDK versions: 10.0.19041.0 -> 10.0.22621.0
-------EDIT
Followed the advice of those who left comments, I fixed the problematic code and it now works fine.
std::vector<std::string> GetAvailableSerialPortsNames() {
  std::vector<std::string> com_names;
  TCHAR lp_target_path[10000];
  for (int i = 0; i <= 255; i++) { // checking ports from COM0 to COM255
    std::string com_name = "COM" + std::to_string(i); // converting to COM0, COM1, COM2
    DWORD test 
      = QueryDosDevice(com_name.c_str(), lp_target_path, 5000);
    if (test != 0) com_names.push_back(com_name);
  }
  return com_names;
}

Querying in main thread. Ports count=3
COM1
COM3
COM4
Querying in other thread. Ports count=3
COM1
COM3
COM4

I still don't understand. What I did wrong was the type conversion of the argument, but why was the correct result output in the main thread case?

I wonder how this can build without #include <windows.h>. Anyway (I think) there aren't any serial ports on my computer, so your code doesn't display any COM port and I can't really test.

My compiler tells me that lp_target_path[10000]; is an index-out-of-range error, that doesn't increase the buffer size at all. (And I also don't have any COM ports).

std::wstring(com_name.begin(), com_name.end()) does not in general produce valid UTF-16. All casts are wrong. They are either not required or mask a bug. Use of TCHAR hasn't been useful in two decades. lp_target_path[10000]; does not resize the array.

That's strange. I fixed all the mistakes you guys pointed out and the problem was resolved. lp_target_path[10000] has been deleted and the problematic function has been changed to DWORD test = QueryDosDevice(com_name.c_str(), lp_target_path, 5000);.

Also does  ::GetLastError() return anything else than ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER?

lp_target_path[10000]; // in case the buffer got filled, increase size of the buffer. : in spite of your comment, this doesn't increase anything, it just dereferences lp_target_path[10000] (which is already UB) and does nothing with the dereferenced value. Not sure if this is the cause of your problem, 5000 should be enough anyway, so this code is probably never executed (did you check that?).

And if it did grow the buffer, the code would end up in an infinite loop, as the call toQueryDosDeviceW() never passes the larger size along.

I can reproduce it after changing Character Set from Use Unicode Character Set to Use Multi-Byte Character Set, which is also indicated by your edited code. I am not interested in the reason but as Unicode in the Windows API/Conventions for Function Prototypes explained,

Your application should always use a generic function prototype with
the generic string and character types.





